# SetContentView acting strangely

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm a new android developer and while I thought I had moved past problems like these I guess not.

This is the deal, in my main class I set the content view and it works fine
setContentView(R.layout.main);

This works the way it usually does, after I type R.layout. it gives me a list of all the layouts I have in the res/layout folder.

In this case:

display_screen

main

seek_bar_preference

Now in a separate activity I created I wanted to set the layout to display_screen, but when I type R.layout. in setContentView, I no longer get the list of `xml` files I saw before, and instead I get other values,

activity_list_item:int

browser_link_context_header:int

expandable_list_conent

it goes on for awhile and is clearly pulling these values from somewhere else other than the layout folder.

Here is the full code of the DisplayScreen activity

```
public class DisplayScreen extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //sets the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.display_screen);
    }


}
```

I HAVE compiled the code
I cleaned the project
I added the new activity to `AndroidManifest.xml`

I have used `setContentView` in other projects without error, so I'm sure it's a small step I missed along the way. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check your imports and make sure you import you R file and not android.R.

Comment: Look at your imports at the top of the Activity class.   Please edit your question and paste them in.

Comment: Haha never mind, the issue was with an import statement pointing the layout filed to the wrong place. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the right `R` class. Typically, it should be `your.package.name.R`. The most common cause for such an issue is the IDE automatically imported the system resource class, `android.R`.

All the layout names you mentioned are included in `android.R.layout`, so correcting the import at the top of your `Activity` will fix the issue.